# how can i pass the id value as a number from the dropdown

Tags: angular

my html contains the following code

```
  <select name ="InCharge" formControlName="InCharge"  class="form-control">
                                <option value="" disabled>Select</option>
                                <option  value="{{name.id}}" *ngFor="let name of gdinchargemstr ;let i=index">{{name.name}}</option>
                            </select>
```

gdinchargemstr  is an object which contains values from an api

my ts file is as follows

```
this.employeeForm= this.fb.group({
Description: ['',Validators.required],
InCharge: [''] ,
ContactNumber: [null],
Address:[''],
Rackdetails: this.fb.array([
this.addRackFormGroup()
])
});
```

Comment: Try `[value]="name.id"`. Also `gdinchargemstr ` should be iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ngValue] instead of [value]

```
  <select name ="InCharge" formControlName="InCharge" class="form-control">
      <option [value]=null disabled>Select</option>
        <option  [ngValue]="name.id" *ngFor="let name of gdinchargemstr;let i=index"> 
         {{name.name}}</option>
     </select>
```